# Trying to use a USB DJ Controller with Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: usb, permissions

I have an external USB/HID DJ controller that should work with Mixxx.  There appears to be some sort of USB/HID permissions issues and the software can't access the controller.  I get an error message in the software log that states:

"USB permissions problem (or device error.) Your account needs write access to USB HID controllers. "

I am a convert from Microsoft :) and still learning Linux.  Any thoughts on how I could give my user account USB HID permissions?

Thanks so much.
Adam

Comment: Have you tried running the program as root?

Comment: If it does work by starting the program as root you should still find a proper fix so you don't have to run it as root anymore

Comment: same problem on ubuntu 18.04. controllers are visible with root but not with normal users. I don't find which group must I add to fix the permission

Comment: Is there an update? I have similar issue